# Encoding a list in Python based on order of occurance

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list like this

`['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A+B', 'A+B', 'B', 'B', 'A']`

I want to convert this list to like this

`[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]`

What I did is, I will start with value `1` and when there is a change in value from the list I will increment the value in hand by one.

This is the code that I am using now,

```
counts = []
count = 1

for i in range(1, len(p)):
    print(p[i-1], p[i])
    if p[i-1] == p[i]:
        counts.append(count)
    else:
        counts.append(count)
        count += 1

if p[-2] == p[-1]:
    counts.append(counts[-1])
else:
    counts.append(counts[-1] + 1)
```

How to do this in Python efficiently.? I can also make use of numpy if necessay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple way to do that with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A+B', 'A+B', 'B', 'B', 'A'])
result = np.concatenate([[1], 1 + np.cumsum(data[:-1] != data[1:])])
print(result)
# [1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5]
```

Or with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A+B', 'A+B', 'B', 'B', 'A'])
result = data.ne(data.shift(1)).cumsum()
print(result)
# 0    1
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    2
# 4    3
# 5    3
# 6    4
# 7    4
# 8    5
# dtype: int32
```